# Calculate Height of JLabel text based on specific Width

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Im working on a Marquee JPanel ,and im using a JLabel to scroll Text within the JPanel by Decreasing the Y of JLabel inside the JPanel .

The issue is i need a Specific Width of JLabel where Height is not important because it will scroll the Text until the Y of JLabel is > than -JLabel.Height which means JLabel last line of text is at Top of JPanel .

So how can i calculate the Height which can hold a sort of Text based on a specific value of Width .

eg.
If Width of JLabel is 50 than the Height should be that value that can fit the text within if text is "Bla bla bla some text over ..." and font is "Serif", Font.ITALIC, 20

Comment: This explanation is way too convoluted. Perhaps take some more time and phrase it better?

Comment: I'm confused; height and width are independent. Is this perhaps about the size of the font used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite that this is answered, I thought I'd offer an alternative approach.  This alternate boils down to 'put the text it in an HTML formatted label'.  The advantage of this approach is that line breaks are normally handled automatically, without having to worry about where to break each line.  E.G.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class HeightOfFixedWidthText {

    public static void show(String s) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(s);
        l.setSize(l.getPreferredSize());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l);
        System.out.println(l.getSize());
    }

    public static void main(String[] srgs) {
        String s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu nulla urna. Donec sit amet risus nisl, a porta enim. Quisque luctus, ligula eu scelerisque gravida, tellus quam vestibulum urna, ut aliquet sapien purus sed erat. Pellentesque consequat vehicula magna, eu aliquam magna interdum porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed sollicitudin sapien non leo tempus lobortis. Morbi semper auctor ipsum, a semper quam elementum a. Aliquam eget sem metus.";
        String html1 = "<html><body " +
            "style='font-family: Serif; font-style: italic; font-size: 20px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" +
            " width: ";
        String html2 = "px'>";
        String html3 = "</body></html>";

        show(html1+"200"+html2+s+html3);
        show(html1+"300"+html2+s+html3);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=260,height=884]
java.awt.Dimension[width=390,height=544]
```

### Caveat

1. There is probably some (more) padding in the body of that HTML that needs to be removed in order to get the *smallest* size needed to display the the text.  Left as an exercise for the user.
2. Swing's HTML formatting is notorious for getting the 'baseline' of text wrong.  This is likely to count if the text content includes things like sub-scripts which drop below the usual baseline of the text.  It seems as though that won't be a problem in this use-case.
3. I only just noticed that though the width is specified as 200 then 300, the result comes back as 260 & 390.  I could understand if that difference was constant between the two (extra padding to remove), but am quite mystified as to why it is different for each label.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the [FontMetrics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) class, which has methods for getting attributes of the font such as height, width, ascent, etc. based on font size. Given this information you should be able to work out the height of a particular font / size relative to the width, and vice versa.

Comment: Using FontMetrics you can get a Size Based on String Content and a Font and it will Return a Dimension ,but i need to calculate how much Height i need if Width is 50 ,Font is "Serif", Font.ITALIC, 20 and text is "Bla bla bla whatever.."

Comment: @Cody So find out how long the string is and divide that by 50, multiply by the number of lines you have and you have your height.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dimension` that you get back from from `getPreferredSize()` should be valid anytime after you call `pack()` or `validate()`.